# PHP URL/slug accept chars

Tags: php, slug

I need to write simple routing system, I have only one question.

When I have url/slug like this

```
/article/1/simple-article-1
```

What characters should be allowed there.

Of course letters, digits, '-', '/' and?

Comment: 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@\-' change as per need

Comment: Have a look at this slug generator function http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator and keep the international characters in mind. If you know how the slugified URL is generated, you can adapt your redirect rule.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1  [L,QSA]
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        return false;
    }

    $info = explode('/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What characters should be allowed there.

Usually slugs are all lowercase, with accented characters replaced by letters of the english alphabet and blank characters replaced by a `-` or an `_`. Punctuation marks like the period, comma, question mark, exclamation point, apostrophe and quotation mark are generally removed. It may be also truncated to keep a reasonable length.

The reserved chars that may have a particular meaning in the URI are: `!`, `*`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `;`, `:`, `@`, `&`, `=`, `+`, `$`, `/`, `?`, `#`, `[` and `]`. If the character would conflict with a reserved character's purpose, then the conflicting data must be percent-encoded before the URI is formed.

Once you product the URI from its component parts, if you want add characters that are not alpha, digit, `-`, `.`, `_` or `~` you should always [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it.

Example:

```
/article/1/i!want!use!the!exclamation!mark <-- bad
/article/1/i%21want%21use%21the%21exclamation%21mark <-- good
```